# How can I delete these sequence of columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am pretty sure there is a much easier way to delete these columns. As you can see in the image, the indexes follow a specific pattern.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post external images of code; your question should be self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

This creates your cols.

```
from functools import reduce # some versions need this.

cols = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [list(range(i+1, 155, 5)) for i in range(3)])
```